# I conncted my laptop to a power supply through an usb port. The power supply is 5v as the usb port.Did i damage it?

Tags: usb, laptop, power-supply, power, cooling

I have a cooling pad that draws power from the computer through an usb cable to work. To avoid discharging my computer, i used as a power supply my smartphone charger (removed the phone cable and attached the cooling pad cable).

this is the cooling pad (at 1:15 you can see the pad cable). As you can see the pad cable must be attached to USB-A ports at both ends of the cable.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cupxA9bjaNE

By mistake,while the smartphone charger was plugged i connected the cooling pad cable to my pc usb port instead of connecting it to my cooling pad usb port.
I left it there for some minutes before realising my mistake.

Did i damage it?
The laptop usb port is working fine, but i noticed that the laptop was producing more heat(20% cpu usage, 65-70 celsius) .
also i needed to uninstall obs studio (recording software) because it was sucking too much cpu (last time i used obs studio was yesterday and it was working fine).
I reinstalled the same obs studio version but then it wasn't working because my video cards' drivers were up to date (after updating them obs studio worked fine and returned using normal cpu usage).
Could this issue be connected to the accident?

Comment: Imho, No.......

Comment: @Moab Imho, no too...

Answer (score 0):

> Did i damage it?

It's quite unlikely... *Most* USB ports are protected by over current and reverse current protection circuitry.

You even mention that the port appears to be working okay:

> The laptop usb port is working fine

---

> I noticed that the laptop was producing more heat

> I needed to uninstall obs studio

It's quite unlikely that any potential damage to a USB port would cause the CPU load or temperature to rise.